# Скроллирование html страницы вслед за курсором при зуме

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При помощи js и jQ повесил изменение свойства zoom страницы на колесо мыши. Но при увеличении положение скролла не меняется, и при значительном увеличении страница как бы уходит вверх.

Нужно чтобы при каждом шаге зума страница "проматывалась" вслед за курсором, по аналогии, как это сделано на googlemaps и ему подобным.

Пробовал делать "прибавку" к свойствам `scrollTop` и `scrollLeft`, пропорциональную степени зума, отталкиваясь от координат курсора, но особо не преуспел.

Код зума:

```
var delta;
var isCall = false;
    if(!isCall){
    var zoom = 1;
    isCall = true;
}

function addHandler(object, event, handler){
    if(object.addEventListener){
        object.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    }else if(object.attachEvent){
        object.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    }
}

addHandler(window, 'DOMMouseScroll', wheel);
addHandler(window, 'mousewheel', wheel);
addHandler(document, 'mousewheel', wheel);

function wheel(event)
{
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.wheelDelta){
        delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
        if (window.opera){
            delta = -delta;
        }
    }else if(event.detail){
        delta = -event.detail / 3;
    }
    if (event.preventDefault){
        event.preventDefault();
    }else{
        event.returnValue = false;
    }

    if(delta > 0){
        if (zoom>=20){return;}
        zoom += 0.25;
        document.body.style.MozTransform = zoom;
        document.body.style.OTransform = zoom;
        document.body.style.zoom = zoom;

        // тут сдвиг скроллов при увеличении
        //document.body.scrollTop = 
        //document.body.scrollLeft = 

    }else{
        if (zoom<=1){return;}
        zoom -= 0.25;
        document.body.style.MozTransform = zoom;
        document.body.style.OTransform = zoom;
        document.body.style.zoom = zoom;

        // тут сдвиг скроллов при уменьшении
        //document.body.scrollTop = 
        //document.body.scrollLeft = 
    }
}
```

Comment: Думаете, без вашего рабочего примера на этот вопрос вы получите ответ?

Comment: добавил рабочий пример.

Answer (score 1):

Пока решил таким способом (для увеличения):

```
document.body.scrollTop = yy-$(window).height()/2;
document.body.scrollLeft = xx-$(window).width()/2;
```

где yy и xx - "адаптированные" координаты курсора, т.е. его координаты без увеличения, умноженные на величину зума.

Но это не совсем то что нужно, сейчас при зуме карта смещается на величину отклонения мыши от центра экрана, а не следует за курсором, как хотелось бы.